# Conversion to yuv422p pixel format is incorrect

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, mjpeg

The setup:

1. A camera that live streams h.264 encoded video via RTSP
2. An Android app that uses FFMPEG to grab H.264 packet fragments, convert it to mjpeg frames with pixel format yuv422.
3. A separate app that receives said jpeg images over udp, expects them to be in yuv422 pixel format, and displays the stream.

The bridge between all these components work perfectly, #2 gets frames and sends it to #3, and #3 verifies it receives. However, #3 would not display, and so upon closer inspection of the packets it receives, I discovered in the jpeg image header for every packet that the horizontal-vertical subsampling factor was not what is expected for YUV422. It's 0x22, despite the fact that for YUV422 we should expect halved horizontal chroma resolution (so we should expect 0x21)

This is the ffmpeg command I use:

`ffmpeg -i rtsp://****:*** -vcodec mjpeg -pix_fmt yuv422p -f mjpeg udp://*******`

What could be going on? Does the default codec just not support this conversion?

Comment: The FFmpeg MJPEG encoder supports: `yuvj420p yuvj422p yuvj444p`. See `ffmpeg -h encoder=mjpeg`.

Comment: Share full log of cmd 2

Answer (score 0):

Most video in consumer space is 4:2:0 and not 4:2:2.
So try a pixel format like YVU420 (‘YV12’), YUV420 (‘YU12’) or some other 4:2:0.